# PHP "header (location)" inside IFRAME, to load in _top location?

Tags: php, iframe, header, location

I have a simple form which is inside IFRAME. When user click on SUBMIT, it redirects to a specific page on my server. The function I use for the redirect is

```
 header ('Location: mypage2.html');
exit ();
```

But I want the new page to open in _top location, not inside the same IFRAME that I use. How can I tell the browser to open the new page in _top not inside the IFRAME?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you do if you don't have access to the FORM element and also don't have access to the code of the PARENT page?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are not able to achieve the desired effect in PHP. This is something you'd have to do from JavaScript or add `target` attribute to `<form>`:

```
<form ... target="_top">
```

Comment: +1 good solution. However, it will mess up any server-side error checking if you want to re-direct the user to the original page in case of an error.

Comment: @jeroen I make a field check with javascript inside my simple .html page. I do not need a redirection in case of empty fields. I use alert :)

Answer (score 11):

A simple way directly in PHP to redirect the parent page rather than the iframe:

```
echo "<script>top.window.location = '/mynewpage.php'</script>";
die;
```

The `die;` isn't necessarily necessary, but it is good "just in case" to prevent the script from continuing any further, for example, if javascript is disabled in the user's browser.

Answer (score 10):

You can use javascript to access the parent. You could echo out javascript in your PHP.. so your parent page has this:

```
function changeURL( url ) {
    document.location = url;
}
```

and in your php script, you echo

```
<script>
   parent.changeURL('mypage2.html' );
</script>
```

The reason you can't call parent.document.location is because it's read only - you have to have a function available on the parent to do it.

Answer (score 4):

we can use javascript like this :

```
target.window.location='locationpage.html';
top.window.location='mypage2.html';
```

Answer (score 1):

The best and simplest thing to do is to use the form target element

```
<form action="..." target="_top"> 
<form action="..." target="_parent">
```

either of the target parameters works fine

Answer (score 1):

You can either link to the page using `<a href="pagename.php?Break=Y">Break Out</a>` or use code

```
<?php header("Location: pagename.php?Break=Y"); ?>
```

You then use the following code in the header of the page with

```
if(isset($_GET['Break'])) // 
    {
    $BreakFrame = true;
    $BreakToPage = "pagename.php";

    }

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function changeURL( url ) {
    document.location = url;
}
</script>

<?php if($BreakFrame) { ?>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
parent.changeURL('<?=$BreakToPage?>' );
</script>

<? }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the page that you want to load in _top, add the follow code in the header

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (top != self) top.location.href = location.href;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP 4, to redirect your parent page just add option `'target'=>'_top'` in your iframe's link:

Example:

```php
 <?= $this->Html->link(__('Redirect Parent'), ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'view'], ['target'=>'_top']) ?>
```

All the best!

Answer (score -1):

You can add multiple headers to your redirect.
I use a little function that I created with this in mind.

```
public function redirect($url){
   header('Window-target: _top');
   header('Location:' . $url, true, 303);
   exit();
}
```

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Sorry didn't have much time when searching for a front-end solution to the same problem.