# How do I fully refresh the page in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-2, reload

I am loading a form in an overlay.  The overlay has a separate controller and action to the page that invokes the overlay.

On form submit, if successful, I simply want to reload the referring page that the overlay was loaded from.  I can get the referring page to load, but it places the content inside the overlay.

```
header("Location: www.example.com", true, 302);
```

does not work.

Using the URL helper like this:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
redirect($url);
```

Also does not work.  Every time it loads in the overlay.  I am sad because of it.

Comment: What are you using for an overlay? If you're using a new window, then you will have trouble trying to refresh the main page. You should be using a fancybox or lightbox or something.

Comment: A bit vague. This refer page when called seperately, the overlay is there or not?

Comment: Btw avoid using `HTTP_REFERER`. It isn't consistent in all browsers and your codes may break.

Comment: How is the overlay generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, using `header` to refresh/redirect will only reflect the changes in the container that is displaying the PHP page.

To refresh the parent page (i.e. the page that is displaying the overlay itself), you will need to do it on the client-side using Javascript. These questions should help you get on the right path:

- [Redirect parent window from an iframe action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580669/redirect-parent-window-from-an-iframe-action-using-javascript)
- [PHP "header (location)" inside IFRAME, to load in _top location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985353/php-header-location-inside-iframe-to-load-in-top-location)

Answer (score 11):

You can use this code to refresh in codeigniter:

```
redirect($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'refresh');
```

it should work!

Comment: It works, but what if I want to go on a particular function with a flash message just with a refresh. It's confusing here. My problem is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55370364/4000266) . @jasmeen , Philip G and Deepti

Answer (score 3):

This one is more simple

> redirect($this->uri->uri_string());

Comment: what if there are params in uri?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to refresh in codeigniter:

```
redirect($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'refresh');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can change $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to whatever you url you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to supply additional two arguments for `header`. Just use this pattern:

```
header('Location: www.somewhere.com');
```

Also, check out this article about a similar matter:

> [Redirect with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723883/redirect-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect(site_url(strtolower(__CLASS__)));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just

```
redirect('/some_url', 'refresh');
```

Comment: more details in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723883/redirect-with-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

**First load under constructor method like as:**

```
function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
$this->load->library('user_agent');
}
```

**After inserting or update add this method it will work fine.**

```
redirect($this->agent->referrer());
```

Answer (score 0):

I some cases you may need

```
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score -1):

This one is more simple for everone :)
location.reload()

Comment: this is jquery not php

Comment: this is vanilla javascript, not jquery