# Reload current URL in Codeigniter After Submit The Form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one form in my view.php file. Its URL like https://example.com/members/view/1, https://example.com/members/view/2 etc. When I submit form its calling model through controller like below

```
public function insert_comments(){



        $data=$this->input->post();



        $this->load->model('work_model');



        $result=$this->work_model->insert_comments($data);



        if($result)



        {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('insert_comments','your comments succesfully');

                $this->session->set_flashdata('succesfully','alert-success');

                $this->load->view('add_coments');

        }

        else{


            $this->session->set_flashdata('insert_comments','your comments failed');

                $this->session->set_flashdata('succesfully','alert-danger');

                $this->load->view('add_coments');

        }

    }

}
```

and model is like below

```
public function insert_comments($array)

{

    return $this->db->insert('comments',$array);

}
```

Currently its working fine and on form submit its loding view called add_comments, instead I want reload/refresh current page. I am not able to get idea of how I can do it, let me know if someone can help me for do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45955173/4641073), in the controller you can use:

```
redirect($this->uri->uri_string());
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
redirect($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are reloading or redirecting a page you should always use the `redirect()` method instead of loading a view.

Redirection basically uses the `header()` method of core PHP and redirection will never execute the code blocks written beyond the `redirect()` method. But in the case of loading the view, it can execute until the end of the code block.

In your code, replace the line `$this->load->view('add_coments');` with the redirection to the desired controller

`redirect('your-controller','refresh');`

I hope that helps you.