# Wordpress, iframe, form with redirect only opens inside iframe

Tags: wordpress, redirect, iframe

I use wordpress, I have a signup form within a small iframe on my site.  Upon submission the user is to be redirected to a thank you page.  Right now the redirect only occurs within the small iframe box, not to whole page.

How do I get the user to be redirected to the new url for the WHOLE PAGE? (not just inside the iframe)

Thanks -cheers

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985353/php-header-location-inside-iframe-to-load-in-top-location) has some options that might work, depending on your particular case, such as using `target="_top"` in your `form` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I used handle form submit event in js with redirecting parent window.

Example for Fluent Forms plugin:

```
$form.submit(function(e) {
    // if form is not in iframe - no action needed
    if (top && top.window) {
        top.window.location = 'https://worldofawakening.com/thanks-for-registration-on-paradanta-meditation/';
}  });
```